# Anything like SqlBulkCopy for Update statements?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

This application I'm developing will read in a bunch of records, validate / modify data, then send that data back to the DB.

I need to do this with an "All or None" approach; either update all of the rows, or don't modify any of the data in the DB.

I found the [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x(v=vs.110).aspx) class which has a method for writing all of the rows in a `DataTable` to a database but this is unacceptable for my purposes. I just wrote a quick app that'd write a few rows to the DB, populate a `DataTable` from that database, modify the data, then call `WriteToServer(DataTable dt)` again. Even though the `DataTable` has all of the Primary Key information, it simply added new rows with the data and new primary keys rather than updating the data for the rows that have matching primary keys.

So, how can I do bulk Update statements to an MSSQL database from a C# Winforms application?

I don't think this is really relevant, but I'll include my code anyways. I'm not great when it comes to interacting with databases, so it's very possible I'm just doing something dumb and wrong.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("myConnectionInfo"))
    {
        //DataTable dt = MakeTable();
        DataTable dt = FillDataTable(conn);

        using (SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
        {
            sbc.DestinationTableName = "TestTbl";

            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    dt.Rows[i][1] = i;
                    dt.Rows[i][2] = i+1;
                    dt.Rows[i][3] = i+2;
                }

                sbc.WriteToServer(dt);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key To Continue");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}

private static DataTable MakeTable()
{
    DataTable newProducts = new DataTable("TestTbl");

    DataColumn TestPk = new DataColumn();
    TestPk.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    TestPk.ColumnName = "TestPk";
    TestPk.AllowDBNull = false;
    TestPk.AutoIncrement = true;
    TestPk.Unique = true;
    newProducts.Columns.Add(TestPk);

    DataColumn Col1 = new DataColumn();
    Col1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    Col1.ColumnName = "Col1";
    Col1.AllowDBNull = false;
    newProducts.Columns.Add(Col1);

    // Add 2 more columns like the above block


    DataRow row = newProducts.NewRow();
    row["Col1"] = "CC-101-WH";
    row["Col2"] = "Cyclocomputer - White";
    row["Col3"] = DBNull.Value;
    newProducts.Rows.Add(row);

    // Add 2 more rows like the above block

    newProducts.AcceptChanges();
    return newProducts;
}

private static DataTable FillDataTable(SqlConnection conn)
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM NYMS.dbo.TestTbl";

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        return dt;
    }
}
```

The call to `MakeTable()` is commented out because I used it when I first ran the application to insert some data, then while trying to update that test data I use `FillDataTable` simply to populate it

Comment: Bulk insert to a temporary table with the same structure, then use the update statement to join with the temporary table and copy data over to existing rows.

Comment: @Matthias `SqlDataAdapter.Update` says "It should be noted that **these statements are not performed as a batch process**; each row is updated individually." I don't see any `SqlDataAdapter.AddToBatch` like selected answer talks about otherwise.